# How would you classify a tensor space equipped with an addition and scalar multiplication?

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

I have been thinking about vectors, vector spaces, tensors, and tensor spaces. So far, I have surmised that a tensor space is defined to be $(\otimes_{i=1}^{k} V,+)$ where the addition is vector addition relative to the component separation caused by the basis vectors and the scalar multiplication is over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

However, I'm confused. Are tensor spaces vector spaces? How do I visualize the notion of a tensor space? I can easily visualize a vector space with examples such as $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I am failing to understand how to visualize higher dimensional structures. Would someone please provide for me some examples of tensor spaces?

Comment: "Tensor space" is not a commonly used term.

Comment: @EricWofsey The most I can find online about it is [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorSpace.html). Is this too obscure?

Comment: MathWorld is not a reliable source, in my experience.

Comment: @EricWofsey What sources do you find reliable? I've been trying to further my understanding of tensors and tensor products for a few weeks now.

Comment: Wikipedia is usually pretty reliable (certainly much better than MathWorld), though it will only provide an overview.  If you really want to rigorously understand these things in detail I would recommend looking at an abstract algebra textbook.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you very much for your educated and informed insight. It means a lot to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take $k=2$.

For an element $T$ in, say $\mathbb R^3\otimes\mathbb R^3$, let us illustrate.

The space $\mathbb R^3\otimes\mathbb R^3$ is generated by the 9 elements
$$e_1\otimes e_1,\qquad e_1\otimes e_2,\qquad e_1\otimes e_3,$$
$$e_2\otimes e_1,\qquad e_2\otimes e_2,\qquad e_2\otimes e_3,$$
$$e_3\otimes e_1,\qquad e_3\otimes e_2,\qquad e_3\otimes e_3.$$

Then $T$ is a linear combination on these.

Symbolically is written as $T=T^{sr}\ e_s\!\otimes\!e_r$, that is a *bi-indexed sum*. Unfold is
$$T=T^{11}\ e_1\!\otimes\!e_1+T^{12}\ e_1\!\otimes\!e_2+\cdots +T^{32}\ e_3\!\otimes\!e_2+T^{33}\ e_3\!\otimes\!e_3.$$

If $T=T^{sr}\ e_s\!\otimes\!e_r$ and
$U=U^{sr}\ e_s\!\otimes\!e_r$ are two of them then
$$T+U=T=(T^{sr}+U^{sr})\ e_s\!\otimes\!e_r,$$
is a vector sum, and
$$qT=(qT^{sr})\ e_s\!\otimes\!e_r$$
is the scalar action.

Now you have a start to begin to grasp. Think with $k=3$ next.

Comment: $k=3$ would be $\mathbb{R}^{3}\otimes \mathbb{R}^3\otimes \mathbb{R}^3$, right? Its basis would come from $27$ tensor products of the unit vectors from $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, for a general space $V$ of $\dim(V)=n$, the basis is a set of cardinality $n^k$? This is starting to fall into place, thank you.

Comment: So, this means tensor products can be taken between both tensors _and_ vectors; tensors themselves being a generalization of a vector? Additionally, 'tensor spaces' (whatever term makes sense for the $(\otimes_{i=1}^{k} V,+)$) probably fail to qualify as a vector space (this is a conjecture, I need to check this or you could tell me)?

Comment: $V\otimes V\otimes\cdots\otimes V$ for any amount $k$ of factors are vectorspaces with basis all possible objects $e_{i_i}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_k}$.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve accepted your answer. @janmarqz